# SoapUI Testrunner giving error about TestAssertionRegistry

Tags: testing, soapui, functional-testing

I am able to run my test case successfully with valid assertions, but when running via testrunner, it starts off with these errors -

```
ERROR [TestAssertionRegistry] Missing assertion for type [JsonPath Match]
ERROR [TestAssertionRegistry] Missing assertion for type [JsonPath Match]
ERROR [TestAssertionRegistry] Missing assertion for type [JsonPath Match]
ERROR [TestAssertionRegistry] Missing assertion for type [JsonPath Match]
```

Where do these errors come from? I disabled all my test steps but to no avail. It appears to be coming form the project level looking at the xml. I am trying to figure out where it got generated from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more than one version of SoapUI installed? This sounds like your project was created in 5.x and you are using testrunner from 4.x series.

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what happened. I exported from a Pro version and moved it to a free version. I ended up redoing the tests to resolve this. If you want to put that as an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonPath Match is a feature in version 5.2.x of SoapUI. You are trying to open the project in version 4.x, and the project files are not downwards compatible.

I was facing the same problem as you: how do I remove all of them. Here is how I *fake* removed them:

1. Open your `*-soapui-project.xml` in a text editor.
2. Substitute all occurrences of `type="JsonPath Match"` for `type="XPath Match" disabled="true"`. Spaces and double quotes are relevant!

Not pretty, but it works. Also, if you want to go back, just reverse the substitution.

Comment: It actually was the free 5.x version which doesn't have JsonPath feature. That being said, I tried to remove it from all the tests and couldn't do it. In the end, I just rewrote the tests in the free version

Comment: @letstestthis Someone downvoted me, so I noticed this answer. I corrected my answer: JsonPath is available starting with 5. **2** .x, even in the free version.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up, if someone else is using the pro version of the api and have a pro client in which the project is set up, and are still getting this error, you can do this to get your assertion to work via the java api:

```
//register the json path content assertion before the project loads
TestAssertionRegistry.getInstance().addAssertion(new JsonPathContentAssertion.Factory());

//loads the project, test suites, etc.
WsdlProjectPro project = new WsdlProjectPro(projectPath);
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm using the API incorrectly but it doesn't appear the pro assertions are loaded into that registry along with the free-version assertions.