# Missing assertion for type [JsonPath Match] error for a Soap UI project CI run

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui

I have configured a CI run for a Soap UI project using Jenkins and Maven. My test steps have Json Path match assertions. Every time it runs, I get errors as

```
17:46:17,058 ERROR [TestAssertionRegistry] Missing assertion for type [JsonPath Match]
17:46:17,058 ERROR [TestAssertionRegistry] Missing assertion for type [JsonPath Match]
```

Due to the above reason, it skips all the JsonPath assertions associated with a test case step (though assertions like Valid HTTPS are validated successfully).
I am using soapui-maven-plugin:5.1.2 currently. After doing some research over internet, I found if a project is created in a version higher than the version the CI is using, the issue will persist. They recommended to re-write the project with the same version as the system,  as explained at [SoapUI Testrunner giving error about TestAssertionRegistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388320/soapui-testrunner-giving-error-about-testassertionregistry) . I did but nothing changed.

I have tried soapui-maven-plugin:5.2.1 version but that didn't help  either to solve the issue, instead it gave me another error and the build fails

```
EROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [The plugin 'C:\Users\xyz\.soapuios\plugins\SoapUI-Framework -v1.0.jar' has unsigned class files.
```

Please help me to fix the issue as the CI would be useless without assertions.

My pom file contains

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>soapTest</groupId>
<artifactId>soapTest</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Maven 2 SoapUI Sample</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>     
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>         
            <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>            
            <version>5.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>C:\Users\xyz\.jenkins\workspace\Soap-uiTest\Test.xml</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                <printReport>true</printReport>     
                <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>               
                <!--testSuite>Negative test cases - JSON</testSuite-->               
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    <plugin>
    <!-- Extended Maven antrun plugin -->
    <!-- https://maven-antrun-extended-plugin.dev.java.net/ -->
    <groupId>org.jvnet.maven-antrun-extended-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-extended-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test-reports</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <junitreport todir="target/surefire-reports">
              <fileset dir="target/surefire-reports">
                <include name="**/*.xml"/>
              </fileset>
              <report format="noframes" todir="target/surefire-reports"/>
            </junitreport>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-trax</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>     

  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.19.1</version>
   <configuration>
     <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>



</plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>                       
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you installed in the same version of soapui in both desktop and CI server?

Comment: Yes. They both have 5.3.0